# Aconcagua: Base Units - would equality comparison be better than identity?

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I learned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744072/424245) that BaseUnits must be singletons. This has a number of disadvantages, including making client code a bit harder to work with (you have to store the singleton somewhere and provide access to it), and making it harder to serialize code e.g. via Fuel.

What is the benefit of this constraint? (I'm assuming it's so that users are safe if they load two Aconcagua clients which define e.g. `BaseUnit subclass: #Pound` differently)

In practice, is it worth it, or would it be better to treat BaseUnits like value objects? Especially in light of the fact that [the paper](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/Teaching/CoursAnnecy/0506-M1-COO/aconcagua-p292-wilkinson.pdf) itself uses expressions like `1 dollar`, which already precludes units with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote something about it in the other post.

Units are not really Singletons (as Singleton is defined in the gang of four book), and the idea is not to create a class per unit but to instantiate BaseUnit or DerivedUnit, etc., per unit you need.

So, for example you can create:

```
meter := BaseUnit named: 'meter'.
centimeter := ProportionalDerivedUnit basedUnit: meter convertionFactor: 1/100 
              named: 'centimeter'.
```

And then write:

```
1*meter = (100*centimeter)
```

that will return true. 
As I post in the other question, equality is defined as the default, therefore identity is used.

So, you can do two things to make equality works:

1. To have well know objects (using global variables or a global root object to access them as Chalten does)
2. Modify #= in Unit and make two units equal if the have the same name (or create a subclass with this definition of #=)

The main reason to use the default #= implementation are:

1. It is the more generic solution
2. Units (in real life) are unique, so it make sense to be unique in the model
3. It make sense to have one "meter" object instead of creating one each time you need it.

The main disadvantage is like you see, that the first time you see it could be kind of problematic to understand, but again, you only need to have a way to access to the object and problem solved.

Regarding Fuel, the problem can be solved saving the root object that defined all units (like TimeUnit in Chalten) or implementing option 2) :-)

Hope this help! Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Your answer and Sean's question are enlightening for a smalltalk beginner like me. It seems to me that saving the root object won't be enough for all uses cases (what if TimeUnit is already defined in the image loading the serialized data ?) and that the second solution would be better. I will try it in my own code where sadly I had change my code to serialize simple numbers and rebuild the Chalten units when needed, which is quite unsatisfying.

Comment: Thanks, Hernan! If one owns both the Aconcagua units and the client code, then either #1 or #2 could make sense. The particular problem I'm confronting is when you *don't* own the Aconcagua code. For instance, if you're using Chalten or a similar toolkit, is it practical to be forced to be responsible for serializing and materializing the root object? And if best practice is to use globals anyway, I don't see the downside of a looser `#=`